# source command in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, command-line-interface

I'm using the source command in Hive to run an external file that contains a number of Hive UDFS (Plain SQL, like date transformations).  The external file is universal for many scripts; thus, easier to maintain outside of individual scripts.

So, if I have

```
source /tmp/udfs.hql;
select * from tmp1
```

and run in from the command line, i.e.

```
hive -e "......."
```

it works fine.

Of course, if I try to do it in Oozie or a non CLI client, it fails, as source is a CLI command.

**Now the question is: How do I replicate this functionality outside of CLI?  In other terms, how to execute the *source* command in a hive query?**

Comment: can u share more details, like what is the workflow configuration, and what is the Error you are getting, that will help. Also Hive Action should be enabled at Oozie-Site.xml, and Hive Client should be avallbe in all the nodes

Comment: Ok, it has nothing to do with Oozie, actually, it is a limitation of HiveServer2 - need to find a workaround...

Answer (score 1):

Clumsy workaround:

1. use a Shell Action to "compile" the final Hive script from its components, then save it under a specific HDFS directory using a specific name (e.g. Oozie Worklow ID + Hive Action name)
2. use that script in the Hive Action
3. delete the script

Code sample for the shell :

```
typeset CurrentJobInfo CurrentJobId TargetHiveScript
if [[ "$CONTAINER_ID" != "" && "$OOZIE_ACTION_CONF_XML" != "" ]]
then
  CurrentJobInfo=$(/bin/sed -n '/<name>mapreduce.job.name<\/name>/ { N ; s/^.*<value>oozie:action:/:/ ; s/<\/value>.*$/:/ ; p}' "$OOZIE_ACTION_CONF_XML")
  CurrentJobId=$(/bin/echo "$CurrentJobInfo" | /bin/sed -n '/:ID=[^:]*:/ { s/^.*ID=// ; s/:.*$// ; p }')
fi
if [[ "$CurrentJobId" == "" ]]
then
  /bin/echo "ERROR - could not find Oozie Job ID in expected XML config file" 1>&2
  exit 255
fi
TargetHiveScript="/user/johndoe/temp/${CurrentJobId}-DummyHiveAction.hql"

# all these ".hql" scripts are assumed to be available in the CWD thanks to <file> elements in Oozie Shell Action

/bin/cat common.hql common.DummyApp.hql DummyHiveAction.hql | /usr/bin/hdfs dfs -put -f - "$TargetHiveScript"
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]
then
  /bin/echo "ERROR - could not upload Hive script" 1>&2
  exit 255
fi

exit 0
```

In the Hive Action the reference to that file should be

```
<script>/user/johndoe/temp/${wf:id()}-DummyHiveAction.hql<script>
```

PS: I did not test all that end-to-end, just did some copy/paste/edit from bits of code that run on our site. The debugging is all yours :-)